# Why is Windows 7 gone if I change my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, operating-systems

I just replaced a "broken" hard drive in a Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop and it looks like Windows 7 is gone.  Is the operating system saved/stored on the hard drive?  If so, does that mean I need to buy a new OS or is there another way?  I have a warranty on this computer: could a failed HD be covered?

Comment: Hmmmm, _a little knowledge is a dangerous thing_ How did you 'replace' the hard drive?  I don't know if your warranty will survive you opening up the box, and if you've had it done professionally they should have told you about OS replacement issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is stored on the harddrive.

You will need to:

- Reinstall windows from the DVD you got from Dell (if you ticked that EUR 5 option)
- Or find someone with the same windows version DVD and borrow that. (that means the Dell OEM version of it, not a non-OEM version)
- Or download a [legal copy of the DVD](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-59465.iso) and use the CoA on your laptop. (That is the sticker with the five sets of numbers and letter).

Answer (score 0):

**Is the operating system saved/stored on the hard drive?** In your case - YES
**If so, does that mean I need to buy a new OS or is there another way?** That depends of type of license (u also may install some linux distro - for free)
**I have a warranty on this computer: could a failed HD be covered?**  replaced - YES

PS: drive replacement should produce seller, otherwise the warranty may be lost

Comment: Thank you very much, Sloan.  I'll check with the warranty.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, everything that your computer needs to run is inside the hard drive (aside from the BIOS). Yes, you would have to buy a new OS, or if the old drive is not completely dead, you could try to transfer the data too the new hard drive. Try http://clonezilla.org/ if you need to transfer. The warranty may cover it, but it varies from company to company. Try calling their customer service.

Comment: Thank you 1950278.  I'll look into clonezilla and also make that call.